# why app performance is slow down ?? when the camera image in gallery has been stored in imageview

Tags: android, performance, imageview

App performance is slow down since camera image was stored in imageview.

Sometimes application is down. how to fix it??

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == camerabutton.getId()){
            addImageView();
        }
    }

    private void addImageView(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType(MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
        intent.setData(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 100){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(postArea.getWidth(), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                //params.width = postArea.getWidth();


                imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                Uri imgUri = data.getData();
                imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
                postArea.addView(imageView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

postArea is LinenerLayout~ This code is add imageView to Layout

Comment: you are mostly probably running out of memory trying to load a high res image

Answer (score 1):

Convert the uri to bitmap and scale the bitmap to required size or the size of the imageview. This will also reduce the size of bitmap and also the memory used to load it. Try something like below

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 100){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(postArea.getWidth(), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                //params.width = postArea.getWidth();


                imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                Uri imgUri = data.getData();
                //Convert uri to bitmap and reduce its size
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imgUri);
                //scale bitmap to the required size of imageview
                //this way it memory usage will also be less
                //set resized bitmap to imageview
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, imageview_width, imageview_height, false));
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                postArea.addView(imageView);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also compress the bitmap to reduce size.